# Write a recursive algorithm that displays all subarrays (ordered subsets of consecutive elements) of a given array

Tags: python, list, recursion, sublist

I need to write a recursive algorithm that displays all subarrays (ordered subsets of consecutive elements) of a given array. I came up only with non recrusive function that uses two loops. Could you give me any suggestions as how to do that recrusively

```
def sub_lists(my_list):
    subs = [[]]
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        n = i+1
        while n <= len(my_list):
            sub = my_list[i:n]
            subs.append(sub)
            n += 1
    return subs
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. What have you tried? What worked, what didn't what was the error message?

Comment: If recursion is a reusable way to do the same simple process repeatedly, think about how you are currently doing repeated work in your loops. Develop a recursive case, and a base case to break out of the recursion. Play around with these concepts in code, using print() to see your output. Don't give up!

Comment: Hi, did you check the solution? Is it what you wanted?